# where to add system property log4j1.compatibility=true in log4j

Tags: java, log4j, wildfly

I am using wildfly22 with log4j.properties file

```
where we need to add  system property value -
log4j1.compatibility=true.

any help is appreciated.
thanks.
```

Comment: The documentation says a system property https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html#Log4j1.2Bridge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting system properties for Log4j in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70843538/setting-system-properties-for-log4j-in-tomcat)

Comment: Basically since Log4j 2.10 _"system property"_ refers to any property source (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties)).

Answer (score 1):

You can set it via the command line when you run your program.  E.g. `java -Dlog4j1.compatibility="true" myapp`.

See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=java-system-properties

If you use gradle you can include it in  gradle.properties.
https://javabydeveloper.com/gradle-system-properties-via-command-line-step-by-step-example/