# Setting system properties for Log4j in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, log4j, log4j2

From this [article](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html), to enable the Log4j 1.2 bridge, you should

1. Set the system property “log4j1.compatibility” to a value of “true”. Log4j 2 will then add log4j.properties, log4j-test.properties, log4j.xml and log4j-test.xml to the configuration files it searches for on the class path.
2. Set the Log4j 1 system property “log4j.configuration” to the location of the log4j 1 configuration file. The files must have a file extension of either “.properties” or “.xml”.

But how to set the system property if my class is running under Tomcat 8.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to understand what is a system property. Check this

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7054981/3957754

Then, if your concern is just how to add a [system property on tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007837/3957754) like classic ram increment, you just need to add `key=value` to the `JAVA_OPTS` or `CATALINA_OPTS` on some script of tomcat:

```
-Dlog4j1.compatibility=true
```

If you don't want to change some default tomcat file, you could create the `setenv.sh` in the bin folder and add something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

MIN_MEMORY="384m"
MAX_MEMORY="768m"
LOG4J_BRIDGE="-Dlog4j1.compatibility=true"

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms${MIN_MEMORY} -Xmx${MAX_MEMORY} ${LOG4J_BRIDGE}  ${JAVA_OPTS}"
```

Basically tomcat say us: If you want to add, change or override special tomcat settings, add them in the file `setenv.sh` and I will load that vars before the startup.

Here are some `setenv.sh` examples to see more special java/tomcat system properties and environment variables:

- https://gist.github.com/chewbakartik/e8f165f6b8c89d8461abe3c4fc6531c4
- https://gist.github.com/jeduoliveira/9f06ba3f20975c57bc9d0b6e5c1c0462
- https://gist.github.com/patmandenver/cadb5f3eb567a439ec01
- https://gist.github.com/hardyoyo/8664b2171d26adcf7b7e
- https://gist.github.com/lesstif/98dfb8c0eeae28e5edb1

Comment: Thanks JRicardsz. Since I'm running Tomcat in Windows as a service, I use tomcat8w.exe to set the Java Options and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever Log4j documentation says *"system properties"* it actually refers to any available property source (cf. [System properties section](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties)). This gives you a rather large spectrum of possibilities.

If you want to set `log4j.configuration` **globally** for all Java applications, set the environment variable `LOG4J_CONFIGURATION`.

If you want to set it for all applications running on Tomcat, set a Java system property, by either:

- passing the `-Dlog4j.configuration=...` option to the JVM as in [JRichardsz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70843701/11748454).
- adding the system property to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties` which is sourced by Tomcat just after it sets up its own logging system (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66763477/11748454)),
- adding the system property to a `log4j2.system.properties` file in Tomcat's server classpath (e.g. `$CATALINA_BASE/lib/log4j2.system.properties`), which is sourced by Log4j on startup (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/3042e80fc6624e410925e4a264acddad92cc1541/log4j-api/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/PropertiesUtil.java#L427)).
- Putting such a file in your application would be bad practice, since the contents of the file end up in Java's system properties and would apply to **all** applications. If you want to set it for **your application only**, put it in a `log4j2.component.properties` file in your application's classpath.

Comment: Thanks Piotr. I tried catalina.properties and log4j2.component.properties, and they all work. I will use the log4j2.component.propertes way.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a reminder. If you run Tomcat as a service in Windows, you can set the Java Options in tomcat8w.exe application.

[image]

Comment: You could use a stronger statement: you **must** use Tomcat Monitor/Procmgr. If you run the server as a Windows service `catalina.bat` and `setenv.bat` are **not** used.